# tensorflow 点群 predictの予測が全て同じ分類となってしまう

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

#### 悩んでること

PythonとTensorFlowで点群データを分類するコードを下記ページを参考に作成しました。
10個ほどの異なる点群をインプットして実行すると、すべてが同じ分類を返されてしまいます。
コードにどんな改良を加えれば良いでしょうか？

#### 参考URL

https://tensorflow.classcat.com/2021/12/06/keras-2-examples-vision-pointnet/

##### 環境

Windows10
Python 3.9.15
TensorFlow 2.11.0(GPUは使用せずCPUで実行)
Keras 2.11.0

#### コード

**下記コードの実行上の注意点:**
learn関数の第2引数をFalseでデータを訓練し、predict関数で点群を与え分類を判定してます。

```
import os
import glob
import trimesh
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
import json
import random

class pointNet_tf2:
    BATCH_SIZE = 32
    NUM_CLASSES = 3
    NUM_POINTS = 2048
    NUM_X = 16
    NUM_Y = 16
    NUM_Z = 8
    #NUM_X * NUM_Y * NUM_Z = NUM_POINTSであること!!

    DATASET_DIR = 'core\\pointNet\\Datasets'
    # MODEL_FILE = 'ModelNet40_model.json'
    # WEIGHT_FILE = 'ModelNet40_weight.h5'
    MODEL_FILE = 'ModelNet40_model.keras'
    CLASS_FILE = 'ModelNet40_class.json'

    def parse_dataset(self, data_set_dir, num_points):

        train_points = []
        train_labels = []
        test_points = []
        test_labels = []
        class_map = {}
        folders = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_set_dir, "[!README]*"))

        for i, folder in enumerate(folders):
            print("processing class: {}".format(os.path.basename(folder)))
            # store folder name with ID so we can retrieve later
            class_map[i] = os.path.basename(folder)
            # gather all files
            train_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "train/*"))
            test_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "test/*"))

            for f in train_files:
                train_points.append(trimesh.load(f).sample(num_points))
                train_labels.append(i)

            for f in test_files:
                test_points.append(trimesh.load(f).sample(num_points))
                test_labels.append(i)

        return (
            np.array(train_points),
            np.array(test_points),
            np.array(train_labels),
            np.array(test_labels),
            class_map,
        )

    def augment(self, points, label):

        # jitter points
        points += tf.random.uniform(points.shape, -0.005, 0.005, dtype=tf.float64)
        # shuffle points
        points = tf.random.shuffle(points)

        return points, label

    def conv_bn(self, x, filters):

        x = layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size=1, padding="valid")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.0)(x)
        return layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    def dense_bn(self, x, filters):

        x = layers.Dense(filters)(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.0)(x)
        return layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    class OrthogonalRegularizer(keras.regularizers.Regularizer):

        def __init__(self, num_rows, num_cols, l2reg=0.001, **kwargs):

            self.num_features = num_rows
            self.l2reg = l2reg
            self.num_rows = num_rows
            self.num_cols = num_cols
            self.eye = tf.eye(num_rows, num_cols)

        def __call__(self, x):
            x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.num_features, self.num_features))
            xxt = tf.tensordot(x, x, axes=(2, 2))
            xxt = tf.reshape(xxt, (-1, self.num_features, self.num_features))
            return tf.reduce_sum(self.l2reg * tf.square(xxt - self.eye))

        def get_config(self):
            config = {
                'num_rows': self.num_rows,
                'num_cols': self.num_cols
            }

            return dict(list(config.items()))

    def tnet(self, inputs, num_features):

        # Initalise bias as the indentity matrix
        bias = keras.initializers.Constant(np.eye(num_features).flatten())
        reg = self.OrthogonalRegularizer(num_features, num_features)

        x = self.conv_bn(inputs, 32)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 64)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 512)
        x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
        x = self.dense_bn(x, 256)
        x = self.dense_bn(x, 128)
        x = layers.Dense(
            num_features * num_features,
            kernel_initializer="zeros",
            bias_initializer=bias,
            activity_regularizer=reg,
        )(x)
        feat_T = layers.Reshape((num_features, num_features))(x)

        # Apply affine transformation to input features
        return layers.Dot(axes=(2, 1))([inputs, feat_T])

    # コンストラクタ
    def __init__(self):

        tf.random.set_seed(1234)

        self.classes = None

        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(self.NUM_POINTS, 3))

        x = self.tnet(inputs, 3)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 32)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 32)
        x = self.tnet(x, 32)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 32)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 64)
        x = self.conv_bn(x, 512)
        x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
        x = self.dense_bn(x, 256)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
        x = self.dense_bn(x, 128)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

        outputs = layers.Dense(self.NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax")(x)

        self.model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="pointnet")

        self.model.summary()

        self.model.compile(
            loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
            metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
        )

    # 学習、訓練
    def learn(self, root_dir, save):

        # データセットのロード
        # data_set_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
        #     "modelnet.zip",
        #     "http://3dvision.princeton.edu/projects/2014/3DShapeNets/ModelNet40.zip",
        #     extract=True,
        # )
        # data_set_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(data_set_dir), "ModelNet40")
        data_set_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, self.DATASET_DIR)

        # mesh = trimesh.load(os.path.join(data_set_dir, "chair/train/chair_0001.off"))
        # mesh.show()
        # points = mesh.sample(NUM_POINTS)

        # fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
        # ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
        # ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2])
        # ax.set_axis_off()
        # plt.show()

        # データセットのパース
        train_points, test_points, train_labels, test_labels, class_map = \
            self.parse_dataset(data_set_dir + '\\ModelNet40', self.NUM_POINTS)

        self.classes = class_map

        # データセットの増強
        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_points, train_labels))
        test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_points, test_labels))

        train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(len(train_points)).map(self.augment).batch(self.BATCH_SIZE)
        test_dataset = test_dataset.shuffle(len(test_points)).batch(self.BATCH_SIZE)

        # モデルの訓練
        self.model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20, validation_data=test_dataset)

        # テスト
        num_test = 10
        test_data = test_dataset.take(1)
        points, labels = list(test_data)[0]
        points = points[: num_test, ...]
        labels = labels[: num_test, ...]

        for t in range(num_test):
            print("pred test[" + str(t) + "]:answer=" + self.classes[labels.numpy()[t]] + ",pred=" + self.predict(points[t]))

        if (save):
            # 保存
            keras.models.save_model(self.model, data_set_dir + '\\' + self.MODEL_FILE)

            # self.model.save_weights(data_set_dir + '\\' + self.WEIGHT_FILE)

            with open(data_set_dir + '\\' + self.CLASS_FILE, 'wt') as f:
                json.dump(class_map, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': '))

    # 学習済みデータのロード
    def load(self, root_dir):

        data_set_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, self.DATASET_DIR)

        # self.model = keras.models.load_model(filepath=data_set_dir + '\\' + self.MODEL_FILE,
        #     custom_objects={"OrthogonalRegularizer": pointNet.OrthogonalRegularizer})
        self.model = keras.models.load_model(filepath=data_set_dir + '\\' + self.MODEL_FILE)

        # self.model.load_weights(data_set_dir + '\\' + self.WEIGHT_FILE)

        self.classes = {}
        with open(data_set_dir + '\\' + self.CLASS_FILE) as f:
            work = json.load(f)
            for k,v in work.items():
                self.classes[int(k)] = v

    #アップサンプリング
    def upSampling(self, points):

        ret = []

        if len(points) > 0:
            while(len(ret) < self.NUM_POINTS):
                ret.append(points[0])

        return ret

    #ダウンサンプリング
    def downSampling(self, points):

        ret = []

        # 各次元の最小値と最大値を取得する
        x_min = None
        x_max = None
        y_min = None
        y_max = None
        z_min = None
        z_max = None

        for p in points:
            if ((x_min is None) or (x_min > p[0])):
                x_min = p[0]
            if ((x_max is None) or (x_max < p[0])):
                x_max = p[0]
            if ((y_min is None) or (y_min > p[1])):
                y_min = p[1]
            if ((y_max is None) or (y_max < p[1])):
                y_max = p[1]
            if ((z_min is None) or (z_min > p[2])):
                z_min = p[2]
            if ((z_max is None) or (z_max < p[2])):
                z_max = p[2]
            
        # パラメータをワーク領域にコピーする
        x_size = (x_max - x_min) / self.NUM_X
        y_size = (y_max - y_min) / self.NUM_Y
        z_size = (z_max - z_min) / self.NUM_Z
        dim3 = [[[[] for z in range(self.NUM_Z)] for y in range(self.NUM_Y)] for x in range(self.NUM_X)]

        for p in points:
            x = int((p[0] - x_min) / x_size)
            if x == self.NUM_X:
                x = self.NUM_X - 1
            y = int((p[1] - y_min) / y_size)
            if y == self.NUM_Y:
                y = self.NUM_Y - 1
            z = int((p[2] - z_min) / z_size)
            if z == self.NUM_Z:
                z = self.NUM_Z - 1

            dim3[x][y][z].append(p)

        # ワーク領域からランダムに点を抽出する
        while len(ret) != self.NUM_POINTS:
            for x in range(self.NUM_X):
                for y in range(self.NUM_Y):
                    for z in range(self.NUM_Z):
                        count = len(dim3[x][y][z])
                        if (count > 0):
                            idx = random.randint(0, count - 1)
                            ret.append(dim3[x][y][z].pop(idx))

                            if (len(ret) == self.NUM_POINTS):
                                break
                    if (len(ret) == self.NUM_POINTS):
                        break
                if (len(ret) == self.NUM_POINTS):
                    break

        return ret

    # 予測、推論
    def predict(self, points_input):

        if (self.classes is None):
            return 'error(モデルが不十分)'

        sample = points_input

        if (len(sample) == self.NUM_POINTS):
            pass
        elif (len(sample) < self.NUM_POINTS):
            # アップサンプリング
            sample = self.upSampling(sample)
        else:
            # ダウンサンプリング
            sample = self.downSampling(sample)

        if (len(sample) != self.NUM_POINTS):
            return "error(点数が不正)"

        points_output = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor(sample, dtype=np.float64), shape=(1, self.NUM_POINTS, 3))

        preds = self.model.predict(points_output)

        indexs = tf.math.argmax(preds, axis=1).numpy()

        class_name = ''
        for i in indexs:
            class_name += self.classes[i] + ','

        if (class_name == ''):
            class_name = 'error(分類不明)'
        else:
            class_name = class_name[: len(class_name) - 1]

        return class_name
```

Comment: 訓練データのラベル付けに間違いはありませんか？ 訓練中の精度はどうなっていましたか？

Comment: merino様　コメントありがとうございます。
データセットはModelNet40のうち3種類のデータを使ってます。
(40種類だと訓練まで4時間ほどかかってしまう為)
ラベル付けは間違えてないと思います。訓練の精度は0.7くらいです。
learn関数で訓練後のテストでは予測が分散するのですが、
その後、predict関数にアプリで抽出した点群データ10種類ほどをインプットすると全部同じ分類が返ってきます。

Comment: 「点群データ10種類」というのは、データ10個と同じ意味ですか？（predictメソッドの中でアップサンプリングされているのか、ダウンサンプリングされているのかを確認するための質問です）　predictメソッドの中で、predsの値を直接確認するとどうなっていますでしょうか？（推論処理そのものが間違っているのか、predictメソッドの推論後の処理が間違っているかを確認しましょう）

Comment: 「PythonとTensorFlowで点群データを分類するコードを下記ページを参考に作成しました。」とありますが、参考サイトそのままのコードでは問題なく動作しましたか？その場合、参考サイトと変えられた部分はどこでしょうか？

Comment: 返信が遅れてすいません。
「点群10種類」は10個の物体です(1つの物体の点数は2048*3個)です。
アップサンプリングとダウンサンプリングは参考URLにない関数で自作しました。
ちなみに、参考URLのコードは学習用のデータセットの分類を予測する処理しかなく、データセット以外の点群の分類を予測する処理がなかったので、pointNetクラスにpredict関数として自作しました。

Comment: 訂正します。１つの物体の点数は500～600000個ほどです。

Comment: 実際のテストデータが不明なので分かりませんが、点が500だと少ないのかもしれませんね。「１つの物体の点数は500～600000個」のテストデータは目視で分類可能なデータでしょうか？そうであればリサンプリング後のデータは目視で分類可能なデータになっていますでしょうか？

Comment: リサンプリング後の点群を可視化することも可能です。
あと、predictの結果を確認しました。正確には14個の点群をpredictしましたが、
全て[[1. 0. 0.]]となりました。1というキリの良い数値が怪しく感じます。

Comment: 「リサンプリング後の点群を可視化することも可能です。」というのは”目視で分類可能なデータであった”という意味でしょうか？テストデータが分類が難しいデータであれば精度が悪くても妥当かと思いますので確認です。

Comment: 「あと、predictの結果を確認しました。」というのは”self.model.predict(points_output)”の結果である”preds”の値を確認した、ということで良いでしょうか？それが[1. 0. 0.]で全て最初のクラスに分類されていた、ということですね？

Comment: はい。目視で分類可能なデータで、predsはself.model.predict(points_output)の結果です。点群の分類はtensorflowでは不可能なようですね。他のライブラリを試してみます。